# this.props.navigation.navigate is not working (Stack navigator)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

Hello please look at this code. Im having an Entry page and a home page. This is my StackNavigator.js file

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Entry from '../Screens/Entry';
import Home from '../Screens/Home';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Entry" component={Entry} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default StackNavigator;
```

here is my entry page and the button in trying to navigate

```
export default function Entry(props){
 return( <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={styles.logBtn}>
                <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Jost', color: '#1b4034' }}>
                  Login
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity> );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is used in class components and you are using functional component.

Use it like this

```
props.navigation.navigate(...)
```